# What does assert_ok do?

Tags: python

I am not entirely sure if assert_ok is a part of some library (like [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lribeiro.cherrypy.test))
or some builtin method, but what does it mean here: https://youtu.be/HVUTjQzESeo?t=5m40s ?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lribeiro.cherrypy.test

Answer (score 0):

In contrary to [assert](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement), which is a native part of Python, the `assert_ok` is not.

The linked video uses this function (or method, more precisely) to check whether a string contains a valid Python program.